# simple_form nested form select wrapper always displaying error class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a nested form with simple_form and simple_fields_for.

I have a select in a table using:

```
item.input_field :budget_code_item_id, collection: @budget_code.budget_code_items.order(code: :asc), label_method: :select_label, value_method: :id,label: false, include_blank: 'Select a budget code...', class: "text-xs select form-control"
```

The problem is that it renders this:

```
<select class=" error select required form-control text-xs select form-control" label="false" include_blank="Select a budget code..." name="budget[budget_items_attributes][0][budget_code_item_id]" id="budget_budget_items_attributes_0_budget_code_item_id">
   <option value="">Select a budget code...</option>
</select>
```

The error code is being applied to the selects all the time even when the fields are valid. The other input text fields are fine - just the selects.

I can't figure out why it's doing this - the error class should only apply when the field is invalid on form submission.

Comment: What are the columns in your budget model? Could you also provide your query for ```@budget_code```?

Comment: :select_label is a method that returns a formatted label from multiple columns etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be a problem with your query for `@budget_code`.

Try to do this:
In your controller:

```rb
# @budget_code = *QUERY*
@budget_items = @budget_code.budget_code_items.order(code: :asc).pluck(:id, :select_label)
```

In your view:

```rb
item.input_field :budget_code_item_id, collection: @budget_items, label_method: :second, value_method: :first, include_blank: 'Select a budget code...', class: "text-xs select form-control"
```

Comment: :select_label is a method and doesn't work with pluck.  I tried a another column for the label field and the error class is still applied.

Comment: Could you provide ```:select_label``` method?

Comment: Try to do this first to see if it works:
```@budget_items = @budget_code.budget_code_items.order(code: :asc).pluck(:id, :name)```
and
```item.input_field :budget_code_item_id, collection: @budget_items, label_method: :second, value_method: :first, include_blank: 'Select a budget code...', class: "text-xs select form-control"```

It should show only the name. If this works, we know that the culprit is in ```label_method: :select_label, value_method: :id```

Comment: No dice - I had that same idea before and ruled it out.  Also tried your suggestion and confirmed the issue persists.